# Callback- not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I have a file, (lets call it "file1") where I insert a key value and fetch it as well; so here I have my implementation for file1:

```
var rdb;

module.exports = function(_app) {    
    rdb = redis.createClient();
    return module.exports;
}


module.exports.parse = function (name, callback) {
        rdb.set(name, 'myValue', function(err, data) {
            console.log("SET:", err, data);
        });
        rdb.get(name, function(err, value) {
            callback(err, value);
        });
}
```

But when I'm calling my parse function in another file it says parse undefined:

```
var f1;
module.exports = function(_app) {
    app = _app;    
    f1 = require('./file1.js')(_app);
};



f1.parse('test', function(err, data){
    console.log(err, value);           
});
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Thanks Now it does not say parse undefined; it goes to my function and it seems there is a problem with the way I'm setting and getting Redis key, value pair! rdb.get(name, function(err, value) {...} does not work ...

Answer (score 1):

Timing. Put `f1.parse...` inside the `function(_app) {...}`. You are using `f1.parse` before it is loaded.

I.e. when your file is loaded, this happens:

- `f1` is declared
- `module.exports` is defined to be some function (note: the function is not executed yet, so `f1 = require(...)` does not happen)
- `f1.parse` is called, but `f1` is still `undefined`

**EDIT**: A short example, without all the Redis junk:

```
// a.js
module.exports = function(_app) {    
    return module.exports;
}
module.exports.parse = function (name, callback) {
    console.log("parse");
}

// b.js
module.exports = function(_app) {
    var f1 = require('./a.js')(_app);
    f1.parse('test', function(err, data){ console.log(err, value); });
};

// c.js
require('./b.js')("foo");
```

run `node c.js`, and `parse` comes out, no error.

Comment: Thanks @Amadan; what you say makes sense! But still after putting it in module.exports = function(_app) {
    app = _app;    
    f1 = require('./file1.js')(_app);
    f1.parse('test', function(err, data){
    console.log(err, value);           
});
}; still it says parse undefined!

Comment: Sorry I'm new to Node; but console.log("parse"); shouldnt be callback("parse");?

Comment: No, I'm ignoring the callback, just printing something on the screen so you know `parse` function has been successfully called. Of course, you can do whatever you want inside `parse` once you confirm it can be accessed correctly.

Comment: Thanks Now it does not say parse undefined; it goes to my function and it seems there is a problem with the way I'm setting and getting Redis key, value pair! rdb.get(name, function(err, value) {...} does not work ...

Comment: I suggest you move this to the next question (about Redis). This one (about undefined functions) seems to be resolved.